# What could go wrong when transferring Minecraft data through an Xbox 360 data transfer cable?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

I have an issue with a RRoD and my biggest consern is Minecraft - my precious worlds, my data... Is that also transferable? Because it may seem however that Minecraft is a little different from other games considering the fact that you only generate one very specific landscape and build the map up, while Fallout and all those other games have everything already built the same way on every game in the world.

My question is, if I use a data transfer cable to move everything, is all my data going to be transferred and put on the new hard drive the **exact same way** as it was on the Xbox? Same spawn point, same version, same worlds, same skins, clothing, and name? I've been anxious about this specific game for 4 months.

Comment: I know I may have asked this question once earlier on this website and it has one answer that cheers me up but most of the other comments suggested me to use the ask question button to post a question..not the answer question button...this is kinda my first time using this website..

Comment: Thanks for coming back and re-asking, and keeping the site nice and clean. **Welcome to Arquade!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course you can, and nothing will change. Nothing will change, because copying data from one memory to another is like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>. Nothing changes.

For some more clarification: Copying data luckily does not change them in any way. Data are not like a painting, that when you want to copy, you have to re-draw it by hand onto another paper, and in the process make some small errors. When you copy data, eg. bytes, it's like when you copy a number from one paper to another.

If the data transfer is possible, all stuff on your old Minecraft will be exactly the same. To the last detail.

Comment: I've been soooo anxious about something happening to my minecraft world but....it's just xbox 360s are so unpredictable and I don't know what the hard drives and memory is capable of doing or wind up doing

Comment: @lordzack01 Yep, I agree. Every single thing from Microsoft is unpredictable, maybe except Notepad. Including XBox. I hope your transfer goes well, good luck!

Comment: Imma need lots of cheers to keep me from going crazy because this world I've been building is so big and not worth loosing...if it had a price...about $375.99 to sell the world to someone else which I would never in a million dollars do EVER...I was hoping one day it would come on an online world showing page or something like that Maybe called (who has the best world)....

Comment: Also I downloaded the app to this website

Comment: @lordzack01 you could also try it on an empty world to see if it works